# Find rows which  contain non-numeric values in a postgresql database

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which contains data gathered from meteorological observations. The data where ill prepared so they are mistakes when they were inserted to the database. In a recent browse  i've found non-numerical data where they should't be any.

How I can select the rows where non-numerical values exist?

The table's layout is as follows:

```
#\d data.tempe
               Table "data.tempe"
   Column   |         Type          | Modifiers 
------------+-----------------------+-----------
 id-station | integer               | 
 year       | integer               | 
 t1         | character varying(25) | 
 t2         | character varying(25) | 
 t3         | character varying(25) | 
 t4         | character varying(25) | 
 t5         | character varying(25) | 
 t6         | character varying(25) | 
 t7         | character varying(25) | 
 t8         | character varying(25) | 
 t9         | character varying(25) | 
 t10        | character varying(25) | 
 t11        | character varying(25) | 
 t12        | character varying(25) |
```

Comment: or another solution would be to change non-numeric values to a predefined value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [this message on the PostgreSQL mailing list](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-sql/2008-04/msg00168.php), you should be able to use a regular expression.

For example, something like this should nullify the invalid values in t1:

```
UPDATE data.tempe SET t1=NULL
    WHERE t1 !~ E'^[+-]?[0-9]+(\\\\.[0-9]*)?([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?\$';
```

(The regular expression may depend on the data format you expect.)

Comment: hmm regedit? how about then for UPDATE data.tempe SET t1=NULL
    WHERE t1 !~ E'[^0-9]';

Comment: What do you mean "*regedit*"? No, `E'[^0-9]` would exclude anything that contains a number. `E'^[0-9]+\$'` perhaps for positive integers.

Comment: heh sorry a bit tired, I meant "regexp". Your original suggestion along with a bit of tinkering should do the trick. I'll try it tomorrow and I'll post the results!

Answer (score 13):

```
WHERE field !~ '^([0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*|[.][0-9]+)$'
```